Gitlab Runner version=16.10.0
There might be a problem with your config based on jsonschema annotations in common/config.go (experimental feature):
jsonschema: '/runners/0/Monitoring' does not validate with https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/common/config#/$ref/properties/runners/items/$ref/properties/Monitoring/$ref/type: expected object, but got null
What does this mean? although the runners are working well..
Anyone experienced this warn message? Thanks in advance.
Looking for solution

I noticed this error after updating as well.  I see it whenever I install the runners via the gitlab-runner register command.  This is the command I'm using: gitlab-register --non-interactive --url 'https://${VM_FQDN}' --token '' --executor 'shell'.  It's odd, can't find anyone whose researched this well yet.

It looks like they inadvertently introduced this bug in gitlab-runner.
To silence the warning, I wound up able to just add and empty [runners.monitoring] element to the config.toml without needing to test a patch and release gitlab-runner:
(/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml)
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800


[[runners]]
  name = "blah"
  ...
  [runners.monitoring]
  ...

